# How to convert the following time format to epoch time

Tags: python, epoch

given the time in the following format
`Nov 30 20:48:48 +0000 2013`, how can this be converted to epoch time? It will be helpful to know on how to convert epoch time to a presentable format.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: I have tried with time library. and all I know is a quick and dirty way,where i should convert each month to corresponding numerical representation with a `dict()`, and strip off the timezone and then convert it. I just wanted to know, if there is any inbuilt method to handle the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer in the blog
 [sandrotosi](http://sandrotosi.blogspot.in/2010/12/convert-date-to-epoch.html)

```
import time
import calendar
stra ="Sat Nov 30 20:48:48 +0000 2013"
formata = "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y"
print calendar.timegm(time.strptime(stra, formata))
```

Here this will give the converted time in epoch and since am using the timegm(), the time is +0000, while

`mktime()`, then it uses the lcoal timezone

Answer (score 1):

Like this at the command-line:

```
date --date="Nov 30 20:48:48 +0000 2013" +"%s"
1385844528
```

Reverse operation:

```
date --date='@1385844528'
Sat Nov 30 20:48:48 GMT 2013
```

Comment: which is the module to import? I mean I am looking for a solution in python

Comment: This is at the command-line. I guess you'd have to execute it with the subprocess module if you wanted to use the command-line tool. Maybe python has a better way - I do not know.